# Convolution with a convex function

Tags: measure-theory, convex-analysis, brownian-motion, convolution, stochastic-integrals

Let $f$ a convex function, and $j$ a $C^\infty$-function with compact support in $(-\infty,0]$ such that $\int j(s) ds = 1$ and set

$$ f_n(x) = n \int_{-\infty}^0 f(x+y)j(ny)dy $$

Prove that $f_n$ is continuous, convex, converges to $f$ pointwise and $f'_n$ increases to $f'_-$.

Im currently reading Continuous Martingales and Brownian Motion and they use this lemma. The fact that $f_n$ is convex is easy from definition. Im having trouble seeing the rest of the properties, since $f$ isn't necessarily integrable, so i can't use simple mollifier - convolution techniques to use dominated convergence or other teorems (i can't even see it's differentiable).

Any help could be grateful.

Comment: Unless you add something like "$j$ is non-negative", $f_n$ is not necessarily convex.

Comment: The name "convolution" isn't the right one: one should have $f(x-y)$ for that...

Answer (score 2):

Hints for the  proof when $j \geq 0$: $f_n(x)=\int_{-N}^{0} f(x+\frac t n) j(t)dt$ (by a simple change of variable) where $N$ is such that the support of $j$ is contained in $[-N, 0]$. It is quite easy to conclude that $f_n$ is continuous and converges pointwise to $f$.[Remember that $f$ is continuous].

It is well known that $f(x)=f(0)-\int_x ^{0}f_{-}'(t))dt$. Use Fubini's Theorem to conclude that $f_n'(x)=-\int_{-N}^{0} f_{-}'(x+\frac t n)dt$. Since $f'_{-}$ is increasing it follows that $f_n'$ increases to $f'_{-}$.

Comment: Thank you! I still can't see why $f_n$ it's continuous though (Mainly, i can't use dominated/monotone convergence). Both results seem easy if i could exchange limits with the integral.

Comment: @opt $f$  is  bounded on compact sets. We can apply DCT.